# Rename folders after 8 characters

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I need a batch file that will remove everything after 8 characters from a folder name.

The scanning application we use occasionally fails when uploading - this renames the folders to be uploaded from something similar to 00002221 to 00002221_20140226

I have tried using the `ren` command however I am not sure how to make it only rename past a certain point, the first 8 digits are and must be unique.

Comment: `ren ????????* ????????` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is now in comments. To only process the folders

```
for /d %a in (*) do ren "%~fa" "????????"
```

For usage inside a batch file, remember to double the percent signs

Comment: Thank's for the help, an example of one folder is 0100060_2013101817701_20131023093050 - I need everything after the 010060 to be removed from the folder name, will this script be able to do that?

Comment: @tom9z, if you remove a `?` from the code, yes. The indicated folder has 7 initial numbers, not 8

Comment: @tom9z, and, of course (evident but i forgot to mention, so maybe not so evident), you can not rename a folder if anything inside it is in use/open.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the shortname (to avoid possible doublettes)?

```
for /d %a in (*) do echo ren "%a" "%~snxa"
```

`/d` process directories (instead of standard filenames)
qoutes around filenames to prevent syntax errors for folders with spaces
`%~snxa`: `s`hort names, `n`ame and e`x`tension (in case a folder has a dot)

Syntax is for use directly on command line. If you use it in a batchfile, replace every `%` with a `%%`